# Why is ?> showing up?

Tags: php

I'm making a website for a project and in the registration form page I have this code in my file:

```
<?php include 'server.php'; ?>
```

And this shows up in the website:

> ?>

It shows up in the corner of the website, when I remove the code the ?> goes away, that's how I know that this piece of code is the problem.
Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: something inside server.php ?

Comment: Chances are if you view source you'll see it all there. Is this in a `.php` file? Is PHP properly configured to run?

Comment: You say that when you remove it, it goes away. You literally answered your own question.

Comment: Are you running this from an actual web server configured to run PHP, or are you just opening the page from your browser (file...open...)?

Comment: Check the page's source, also if possible, post `server.php`'s content **in the question not in the comments**

Comment: Make sure haven't already closed your PHP script using `?>` prior to the one that's troublesome. And if the first one doesn't show but the second one does, then it's safe to assume that you are running it locally or on a server and PHP is properly configured, as _well_ as it being saved in a `.php` format.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I need that piece of code, I just said that because that's how I know that this piece of code is the problem.

Comment: Sorry if i made any formatting mistakes or any other mistakes, this is my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: @j08691 I'm running it on MAMP.

Comment: @Brxxn The piece of code i mentioned is the very first code in the php file.

Comment: @Xatyrian I feel stupid, it was in server.php. I had a `?>` extra in server.php

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of reasons why this might be happening. I'm going to assume you're running the PHP code (or trying to) on your local computer, right?

1. PHP might not be installed on your computer/server
2. The file has not been saved as PHP
3. Once you declare `<?php`, you don't need to close it with `?>`

Comment: I just had a `?>` extra in server.php. I didn't think to look inside there. I have a piece of HTML code in the php file right after `<?php include 'server.php'; ?>` so i suppose i do have to close it with `?>`.

Comment: You don't need to close it inside `server.php` either, you can have it without. The problem with having two endings is after the first PHP ending, everything else is treated as plain text.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. I had `?> ?>` at the end of `server.php`. I removed both now and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a `?>` extra in `server.php`. (Thanks @Xatyrian)